# Retrieving an ActorSelection from a Trait in akka/scala

Tags: scala, akka, actor, traits

I am new to scala/akka.  I need to create a trait and from this trait, to retrieve actors from a context or directly from an actorSystem.
But I don't want this trait to either extends Actor, nor force to be mixed with an Actor.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Akka :-)

You should create a trait with an abstract method, that will be used to retrieve the actor system, for example like this:

```
trait DoesThings {
  def system: ActorSystem 
  def findActor(name: String) = // do actor selection using system here
}

object Example extends DoesThings {
  val system = ActorSystem("example")
  val ref = findActor
}
```

Happy hakking!

Answer (score 0):

You can put an actor system val in the trait.

And with instantiation you will pass used actor system to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
trait ActorLookup{
  def actorSelection(path:ActorPath)(implicit fact:ActorRefFactory) = fact.actorSelection(path)

  def actorSelection(path:String)(implicit fact:ActorRefFactory) = fact.actorSelection(path)
}

class ActorBasedImpl extends Actor with ActorLookup{

  def receive = {
    case _ =>
      val ref = actorSelection("/foo")
  }
}

class NonActorBasedImpl extends ActorLookup{
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("foo")
  ...
  val ref = actorSelection("/user/foo")
}
```

Within an Actor, you already have an implicit `ActorRefFactory` in scope so no need to define one.  If you wanted to use the `ActorSystem` instead there, you could just pass it explicitly like so:

```
actorSelection("/user/foo")(context.system)
```

Outside an Actor, it's more likely you will be using an `ActorSystem` instead of an `ActorContext` to perform lookups, so that's why an implicit `ActorSystem` was defined.  But again, you don't have to define it as an implicit and could just use it explicitly if desired.